# How to nest views in Spring

Tags: java, model-view-controller, spring, spring-mvc

I'm still just getting my feet wet with Spring, but am curious if it would be possible to somehow build a nested hierarchy of views. The goal would be to have a parent view/JSP with the header/footer of the page, and then have descendant views that would be wrapped with the parent.

Is this possible within the context of Spring's MVC architecture? If so, what my first steps be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [Spring MVC with Tiles](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-tiles). You can configure a parent 'template' tile that contains your header and footer, then have each tile extend that template. You use the name of the tile as your MVC view rather than using the JSP as a view directly.

An excellent way to see how to use Spring MVC with Tiles is to create a project with [Spring Roo](http://www.springsource.org/roo). Roo is a developer tool that helps you quickly start new Spring projects. It will create a new web application for you with all the views using Tiles; and those views will be hierarchical like you describe. Even if you don't use Roo to create your final project, you should find it a useful example of how you can use Tiles with Spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

To roll it yourself, using `<jsp:include>` you can do this.  You might have a controller for an entire page, and the JSP for this page will have one or more jsp includes that refer to other controllers that render further JSPs.  These can use jsp includes all the way down.

Answer (score 0):

See [JSP-based Templating with Spring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/383822/jsp-based-templating-with-spring)

Answer (score 0):

... I opted for a 'home brew' solution only because the project would benefit more from lightness and simplicity of that. If I could be somewhat certain that my project will cross the line where another 'straight jacket' of a presentation framework would be beneficial that would be a different story.