# Master Page for Nav Menu - Partial Views with Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm using spring mvc 3.2.2.  I have a main index page that contains a header for login/user info as well as a navigation menu and a footer (as well as it's own content).

```
> http://localhost:8080/mywebsite/home/index.jsp

<html>....
<head>...
<body>
   <headerbar>...
   <navmenu>...
   <!-- Content here....-->
   <footer>
<body>
```

Now that I will be adding new controllers and actions how can I reuse the header/nav menu and footer so that I don't have to add it in each additional page?

So for my users controller page all I want to have to do is render the user information without having include the header/nav/footer etc.

```
> http://localhost:8080/mysite/account/user/8585

<!-- Only include the following but have it render as body() where nav menu/footer/header are already included in some partial view or master page -->
<h4>User Account</h2>
<user>${username}</user>
<firstname>${firstname}</firstname>
```

How can I accomplish this?

```
<html>....
<head>...
<body>
   <headerbar>...
   <navmenu>...
     RenderBody?() <!-- Content here from any page include home/index.jsp and account/user....-->
   <footer>
<body>
```

Comment: Um....the duplicate that you reference as marked is over 5yrs old?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/383822/jsp-based-templating-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

You need some kind of template engine to solve this, for example [Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/)

Comment: Thanks. If not tiles then what does the java/jsp community use otherwise?  Do they reload every single html page/view with nav/bar/footer, etc,.less another template library?

Comment: Do you mean what other template engines (except Tiles) there are on market now? If so - there are quite bunch of them. Have a look on comparison table from wikipedia (far from complete) here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_engine_%28web%29 , for example. Personally I suggest Tiles because it was a good fit for my projects ~2 years ago and it pretty much satisfied my needs so far.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I was just curious what the market and community over all is using. There's a ton of websites that use java and I'm coming from a .net background.  I have read that sitemesh is much easier to use than tiles in that you don't have a tile to create for each jsp to redirect to....not sure if that is the case with tiles3 but I'm looking for performance and less configuration. But I will submit to ridicule here. In fact I don't even see sitemesh listed in that wiki list.

Comment: I don't wanna be a sissy, but any chance you could include a sample of syntax using that library?